# How to add a local cordova plugin with ionic / ionic 2 / ionic 3 / ionic 4 / ionic 5?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I currently develop an app with ionic, and my cordova plugin in the same time. I wanted to know how to use the file `plugins/fetch.json` to update my plugin from a local file system. Any idea ?

Comment: How to import plugin which added from local folder? Following line is not working: import { facedetector } from '../../../plugins/cordova-plugin-ezar-facedetector'; @GuillaumeLeMière

Comment: Hi @MohdSadham!
You are supposed to import your JavaScript interface like any other JavaScript library. Once you run the command in the accepted answer below, your plugin should be available in window.cordova.plugins.

I recommend you to follow the @ionic/native pattern of creating your type definition in a separate project and then use it in your ionic app, but it's not required if you need something that work fast.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To add a local plugin with ionic :

```
ionic cordova plugin add /path/to/my/plugin/my.plugin.folder.here/
```

to remove it :

```
ionic cordova plugin remove my.plugin.folder.here
```

But to update it it's another problem. Actually I'm removing and installing it again after each edit. Good luck ;)

**EDIT**

If you are using a previous version of ionic cli, and it doesn't work, change the commands to the following :

```
ionic plugin add /path/to/my/plugin/my.plugin.folder.here/
```

and

```
ionic plugin remove my.plugin.folder.here
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an « import » command to my knowledge. I think you are confused with the ES6 import statement that you are supposed to use in your js/jsx/ts files.

Comment: How to import plugin which added from local folder? Following line is not working: import { facedetector } from '../../../plugins/cordova-plugin-ezar-facedetector'; @GuillaumeLeMière

Comment: @mohd-sadham I guess you want to do a ionic-native-like import in your ionic project? Check out this tutorial https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/how-to-write-an-ionic-cordova-plugin-in-swift-8d443430b27d

Answer (score 11):

If you are using [plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman) then

```
plugman install --platform android --project path/to/your/ionicapp/platforms/android --plugin /Path/to/your/cordova-plugin/MyDemo/
```

will install the plugin, read other options in project's [readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman#plugin-management).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Capacitor** then you should run ***npm***. Like:

```
 npm i path/to/your/cordova-plugin
```