# How to properly update a ionic 2 plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am working on a ionic 2 app and would like to add a function which is not implemented yet in the [BLE plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ble/).

I have installed it in my project, and I can edit the code by modifying some local files like :

- plugins/cordova-plugin-ble-central/src/wp/BLECentralPlugin.cs
- plugins/cordova-plugin-ble-central/www/ble.js
- node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/ble.d.ts

And some other files in the "node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/" folder.

But I am afraid that if I update ionic, it will erase my changes. Is there a "safe" way to update a ionic 2 / cordova plugin ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to create a pull request to the plugin repository, asking them to implement the functionality you need.

Second to that, imo, is creating a fork of the plugin and using that, but that would mean you can't update the plugin to include all the changes that the main repository has.

And another option would be to add the plugin locally, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic-ionic-2-ionic-3-ionic-4). Which would mean that you would have to handle updating it by yourself, but at least then your changes won't be overwritten by accident.