# How to add a local plugin with cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

when i use the command :ionic cordova plugin add MyPlugin 
.it throw an error : Error: Invalid Plugin! MyPlugin needs a valid package.json
but i have used the commend :plugman createpackagejson MyPlugin ,MyPlugin is the local design plugin ,but add fail.

[image]

ionic version :3.8.0

cordova version:7.0.1

Comment: Finally solved the problem, it was cordova's environment went wrong, reinstalled and then it was ok, and the version number did not change!!!

Comment: I answered this question a few years ago ;-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/resolved-how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic-ionic-2-ionic-3-io