# How to remove installed ionic cordova plugin from ionic 2 / 3 or ionic V2+ project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I installed Cordova and Ionic Native plugins into the ionic3 project.

But I need to remove only that specific Cordova and Ionic Native plugins from the project completely. (With its dependencies like `npm`).

Is there any proper way to do that?

Appreciate any kind of your help.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say `plugin` do you mean native plugin or the external plugins downloaded by npm?

Comment: i mean native plugin and it's npm dependencies

Comment: you can simply use ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin name>

Comment: If the answer is helpful then please accept it, so it will help to others too

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I just refer their document [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/plugin/).

Example:

To **install** a plugin we are using following way.

**`ionic cordova plugin add <plugin-name>`**

(`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs`)

**`npm install --save @ionic-native/<npm-name-of-plugin>`**

(`npm install --save @ionic-native/dialogs`)

To **Uninstall** the plugin just need to revert above things back as bellow

**`ionic cordova plugin remove <plugin-name>`** or `ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin-name>`

(`ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-dialogs`) or (`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-dialogs`)

Finally uninstall the associated Ionic Native package(s) from npm

**`npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/<npm-name-of-plugin>`**

(`npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/dialogs`)

The --save flag will remove the project's package.json entry for that plugin

Doing above things helps me to remove plugin completely with its npm dependencies from the project. Hope this will useful to someone else

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to remove

```
ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin name>
```

Example :

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera
```

Please check the similar type of question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic-ionic-2-ionic-3-ionic-4).

Also please check the documentation of plugin commands from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/plugin/).

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 3):

please make sure that you also run **npm uninstall** after **ionic cordova remove** skipping this may lead to serious consequences like for instance the BUILD is successful but some of features in the App fails in the runtime complaining the plugin is missing, what must have happened in this case is re installation must have silently failed as the plugin source still exists due to not performing **npm uninstall**, such mistakes do happen while migrations, upgrade to new CLI. In my case InAppPurchase2 plugin did not work, payments stopped working :(, something quite miserable isn't it..hope the lesson helps someone out there..

Answer (score 2):

Try below

`ionic cordova plugin remove <PLUGIN_NAME> --no-interactive`

[READ MORE](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/remove-plugin-from-ionic/14830/2)

Hope this helps