# can we modify cordova plugins(cordova-plugin-fcm) and use in our project?

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am stuck in my project for sending image with push notification. Thats why I am trying to change cordova plugin i.e. cordova-plugin-fcm for sending push notification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can clone/download [that plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm), modify it; then you can add it to your project from a local directory, by using this command:

```
cordova plugin add "path/to/your/plugin"
```

You can also add `--noregistry` option, to skip searching for the plugin in repositories. ([Documentation of `plugin` command](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-plugin-command))

Or if you are using Ionic, you may want to check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345035/how-to-add-a-local-cordova-plugin-with-ionic-ionic-2-ionic-3-ionic-4).